# Plugin not starting with application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have an RCP application that has several plugins defined in it for data and functional seperation.

I need all of the plugins to activate when the application starts (a couple of them need to register for network events). I have the "Activate this plug-in when one of it's classes is loaded" box unchecked, from looking at the xml when this box is checked and unchecked it appears that this is actually a lazy loading indicator.

If I add the plugins to the configuration page in the .product I get ClassNotFoundExceptions for each of the activators.

What is the best way to get a plugin to start automatically when an RCP application starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd rather that plugin have minimal knowledge of the other plugins

In that case you can do what Eclipse does: define an extension point in launcher and let all plugins that need to be started extend that extension point.

Comment: I haven't done much with extensions, I found this tutorial that shows how to create them:     
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html#extensionpoints_overview     
Is there a way to do this without each client needing to implement an interface that does nothing?

Comment: @SamBrinck Yes, sure. Only required attributes of an extension point are name and ID. Check out [Plug-in Extension Points](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/extension_points.htm) in Eclipse help.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn on the "Activate... when one of it's classes are loaded" and then just make sure you touch all of the classes you need at startup time (which you will have to do anyways to get your code going). I think there are some deprecated methods of forcing plugin activation at startup, but you should not need to go there. In general, just calling a class in the plugin will cause it to be loaded and started if everything is set up right, you should not need to do anything special.

Your app presumably has one of the classes called by the Eclipse boot (like `WindowWorkbenchAdvisor` or something like that (there are many hooks in the boot), just pick the one that makes sense and call your code.

Comment: I have a launcher plugin that takes care of the workbench interaction. I'd rather that plugin have minimal knowledge of the other plugins, but if I can't find anything else I will do that. Thanks

Comment: Another thing you can consider is to explicitly start the plugins by modifying the `config.ini` file and adding them to the `osgi.bundles` property.